# CQL query from PostGIS using GeoTools

Tags: postgis, geotools, cql

I have a shapefile (points) loaded in PostGIS. What I want to do is execute an ECQL query using geotools filtering points within a certain radius (10 kilometers) from a specific point (user input). Then output a list (table) with the resulting filtered points. I want the output table in a way that I can later call it (as a class) in a Java code for some other algorithms.

Comment: does http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/tutorial/filter/query.html help?